# Dnsmasq - DNS plain lookups not working, though qualified lookups and host records seem correct

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq

I've got a simple [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) setup, but am encountering an error. In particular, the following is not working as I'd expect it to: pinging the plain domain fails, but pinging a local-qualified name works. i.e.:

```
$ ping xerox
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
.... (always times out)

$ ping xerox.abc
64 bytes from 10.0.0.51: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.233 ms
.... (always works)
```

However, the lookups with the `host` program work as expected:

```
$ host xerox
xerox has address 10.0.0.51

$ host xerox.abc
xerox.abc has address 10.0.0.51
```

I'd like to know why the plain names don't work, and how one might go about fixing it.

Here's my dnsmasq config:

```
bogus-priv
local=/abc/
domain=abc
dhcp-range=10.0.0.100,10.0.0.200,24h
dhcp-option=option:router,10.0.0.1
dhcp-option=option:ntp-server,132.246.11.229,132.246.11.227
dhcp-option=19,0           # option ip-forwarding off
dhcp-option=44,0.0.0.0     # set netbios-over-TCP/IP nameserver(s)
dhcp-option=45,0.0.0.0     # netbios datagram distribution server
dhcp-option=46,8           # netbios node type
dhcp-host=xerox,10.0.0.51,infinite
dhcp-option=vendor:MSFT,2,1i
dhcp-authoritative
local-ttl=21680
log-queries
```

Incidentally, when I run a diff the following lines are different from `hosts -v` (though I am not knowledgable enough to say whether or why this may be relevant):

Lines 13-14

xerox:

```
< ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 3769
< ;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

xerox.abc:

```
> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45183
> ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

and lines 21-22

xerox:

```
< ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11111
< ;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

xerox.abc:

```
> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42629
> ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

Thank you for reading, and I'm grateful for any assistance you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simple:

Mac OS X (from where I was testing it) was caching an old lookup of `xerox` with a different IP. I cleared the cache with `dscacheutil -flushcache` and voila.